# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'String' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php:340

Tags: debugging, cakephp, xampp

I have upgraded my XAMPP to "ApacheFriends XAMPP Version 7.0.15" and now the error below keeps appearing. I have configured the Virtual Host under http.conf for Apache as it is not existing anymore but still it produces same error. Not sure if this error cause by the latest version of XAMPP or if I miss something to configure. Appreciate any answers and help. Thank you.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'String' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php:340 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php(742):
>   Debugger::trace(Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php(219):
>   Debugger->outputError(Array) #2 [internal function]:
>   ErrorHandler::handleError(2, 'srand() expects...',
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 190, Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\lib\Cake\Utility\Security.php(190):
>   srand('768593096574535...') #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\CookieComponent.php(530):
>   Security::cipher('\xFA\xC1\xA1\x1C\xAE)6\xD5\xA2\xD3\x15rk\x14m...',
>   'DYhG93b0qyJfIxf...') #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\CookieComponent.php(507):
>   CookieComponent->_decode('\xFA\xC1\xA1\x1C\xAE)6\xD5\xA2\xD3\x15rk\x14m...')
>
> ## 6 C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\CookieComponent.php(270):
>
> CookieComponent->_decrypt(Array) #7
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\Controller\AppController.php(171):
>   CookieComponent->read('remember_me_ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php on line 340

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xampp or Apache. You have a PHP framework and you've upgraded the PHP version without checking first whether the new version is supported by your framework.

Comment: you need to update your cakephp version to >=  2.8 , it will be better even to migrate to 3.x version of cakephp

Answer (score 0):

> Deprecated since version 2.7: The String class was deprecated in 2.7 in favour of the CakeText class. While the String class is still available for backwards compatibility, using CakeText is recommended as it offers compatibility with PHP7 and HHVM.

`String` class is deprecated in `CakePHP`, use `CakeText` instead

An example of usage :

```
App::uses('CakeText', 'Utility');
CakeText::toList(array('A','B','C')) // outputs 'A, B and C'
```

Comment: @see [CakePHP String Class](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/string.html)

Comment: This doesn't explain why it worked with an earlier PHP version.

Comment: It's beacause `String` is a reserved word in PHP7, earlier versions of Cakephp didn't target PHP7 until v2.8.0

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the most recent version of XAMPP that support Php 5 as my CakePhp version isn't compatible with the PhP 7 and this resolves the issue and manage to work on the latest Laravel as well.